# Making broken love smile again!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, visual

A friend of mine stopped by last night. Sad, depressed, was about to cry when I asked him, what's wrong. He narrated this story to me -

---

Today at cafe, I met her. We had a little chat where I was expressing my love for her, and she was just bashing my words.

> Me  : *Honey*
>   She : Don't dare try talking to me
>   Me  : You are *My Queen*
>   She : I don't care
>   Me  : But you know, *I Love You*
>   She : Go to hell. That's a lie
>   Me  : Baby, *I can't live without you!!!*
>   She : Please stop talking this nonsense
>   Me  : Try to understand *Life is tough without you!!!!!*
>   She : I can't believe you have guts saying that
>   Me  : Honey, *You are the queen of my life!*
>   She : I was. Now, I don't mean anything to you.
>   Me  : I promise, *I can do anything for you!!!!*
>   She : I can't take this anymore. You never trusted me a bit.
>   Me  : But, *I trust you and I adore you*
>   She : I hope you remember the last time we talked. It's not going to change. You know that very well.
>   Me  : My love for you is *to eternity!* and beyond.
>   She : I am leaving now. I don't want to see you again.
>   Me  : But, I have waited for you *a lot!!!*
>   She : I hope you rot in hell.
>   Me  : *Marry me Love!!* Please. I beg you.
>   She : What the hell! I just bashed you. Are you out of your mind?
>   Me  : *I miss you!!*
>   She : I miss you too. But its over. Believe me.
>   Me  : *My Baby!* please wait
>   She : Okay. I am leaving. That's enough.
>   Me  : *Love* please ....
>   She : Bye forever..................

So, that's how it went. I wish if my words were hers I would have been on the top of the world. But well, this is what happened. Can you help me?

---

I remembered his story and carefully made a note for him to solve. I guess, we might help him a little with some smiles at least. Can you test solve for me? Lets fulfill his wish.

```
     Don't dare try talking to me       I don't care
   Go to hell. That's a lie  Go to hell. That's a lie.
 Please stop talking that nonsense
I can't believe you have guts saying that
I was. Now, I don't mean anything to you.
I can't take this anymore. You never trusted me a bit.
 I hope you remember the last time we talked. It's not going to change. You know that very well.
   Go to hell. That's a lie I am leaving now. I don't want to see you again.
     Go to hell. That's a lie I hope you rot in hell.
       What the hell! I just bashed you. Are you out of your mind?
        I miss you too. But its over. Believe me.
          Okay. I am leaving. That's enough.
            Bye forever..................
             !
```

Comment: does the double 'Go to hell. That's a lie' in the text mean something or just a misspell?

Comment: @FrancescoRoggia No misspells. All fine :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The wish was *if my words were hers* and the title speaks about broken heart so, changing each phrase in the notes by the words in italic previously said by him, you make the shape of a heart. The result is:
>
>  **IMAGE VERSION**
>
>
>     [image]
>
>
>  **OP EDIT** 
>
>  **ASCII Version**
>
> ```
>      Honey       My Queen
>    I Love you  I Love you.
>  I can't live without you!!!
> Life's tough without you!!!!!
> You are the queen of my life!
> I can do anything for you!!!!
>  I trust you and I adore you
>    I love you to eternity!
>      I love you a lot!!!
>        Marry me Love!!
>         I miss you!!
>           My Baby!
>             Love
>              !
> ```

Comment: ,it's amore... Gotta be it, good answer.

Comment: Nicely done! I've added a little in there. Thanks for test solving :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something to do with

> bees.

Because of

> all those references to *honey*, and the *queen* bee, without whom the other bees would die.

I'm not sure if there's anything else to solve here, or what you mean by "test solve". Is it just a simple riddle with a hidden meaning, or is there some kind of visual puzzle going on in that code block?

Comment: Oh you posted an answer? No. Not that straight. Offcourse you need to utilize the note, the story as tag suggest. :-) And, no riddle tag here.